# Can I update a value on the fly in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update, concatenation

I'm trying to run do this database transaction in one mysql query instead of messing about with the data in PHP. Problem is I'm not great at mysql. I'm trying to remove a leading zero, then add 44 to the number to standardise the data, then update some columns. I could do with leaving the data that I CONCAT and TRIM intact though.

This is what I have so far...

```
UPDATE calldata AS gcd 
JOIN tarif AS ap 
ON CONCAT('44', TRIM(LEADING 0 FROM `gcd.n_dialled`)) 
LIKE CONCAT(ap.prefix, '%')
SET gcd.prefix=ap.prefix, gcd.dest1=ap.dest
WHERE gcd.countrycode='UKN' 
AND gcd.citycode=''
```

I'm not getting an SQL error, just internal server error

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df7913/ sqlfiddle

Comment: can you put the schema of the tables and a couple examples of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Are you running this query with PHP?  It may be throwing an uncaught exception.  Turn error reporting on

Comment: can u provide SQL Fiddle?

Comment: Hi I've added the fiddle. Thanks never knew that existed!